# How to convert string into array of object?

Tags: javascript

```
let str="{SPOT:0,0:10,1:0},{SPOT:1,0:5,1:5}";
let result=[{"SPOT":0,"0":10,"1":0},{"SPOT":1,"0":5,"1":5}];
```

How to convert string to array of object

Comment: Using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to return an array of  'object string'. Then, using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse each object string to object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make it look like an array using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and a little bit of [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

When it looks right we can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to actually turn it into an array

Now we have an array we can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to go through each string and make them look like objects, we'll use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) again.

Once we've made each string look like an object we can [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) them into an empty results array, we'll have to make one outside of the loop.

Putting all this together looks a little like this:

```js
const str = "{SPOT:0,0:10,1:0},{SPOT:1,0:5,1:5}";
let result = [];
JSON.parse(`["${str}"]`.replace(/},{/g, `}","{`)).forEach((e) => {
  result.push(JSON.parse(e.replace(/{/g, `{"`).replace(/:/g, `":`).replace(/,/g, `,"`)));
});

console.log(result)
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: How to make spot property name as a first property of the result array Object.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not the best approach I would say but still, it will solve your problem:

```js
let str = "{SPOT:0,0:10,1:0},{SPOT:1,0:5,1:5}";
let newStr = str.replace("},{", "}TempString{"); //append any dummy string in the existing one
let result = newStr.split("TempString");

console.log(result)
```